# Docker: Container command '/bin/sh' not found

Tags: docker

When i try to build docker images using the command `docker build -t opencv:2.4.11 .` I get following error.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 189.8 MB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:trusty
 ---> b72889fa879c
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 689f34e138c2
Container command '/bin/sh' could not be invoked.
```

My docker client and server version are:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:34:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:34:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Any idea?

I have softlinked my `/var/lib/docker` directory to one of directories present in my home. And that directory is owned by root. Is this the source of problem?

Before moving and softlinking it was fine. I ran out of space in my root partition and so I had to change it to my home partition.

And my home partition is `ext4` file system.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks badly hosed.

> I have softlinked my /var/lib/docker directory to one of directories present in my home.

I would recommend amending the daemon parameters to include `-g your_other_directory` instead.  Then stop and restart Docker.

If it still doesn't work, delete both Docker directories, re-install, and start at the `-g` step again.

Comment: Thanks! this exactly what I am doing now. I was just wondering why symlinks dint work in this case.